# Characterizing different chain links

Tags: knot-theory

Imagine I have 3 rings (or any other closed line) which cannot twist (by twist I mean as in the Whitehead link, for example). There are 3 ways to link them, one of which is the Borromean rings configuration.

My question is two-fold:

- Which quantities are enough to characterize completely one configuration, so that, by giving the specific values of those quantities to someone, they will be able to reconstruct the configuration I'm talking about.
- Are those quantities generalizable to N rings?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** By "rings that cannot twist" I mean something like a hula hoop with a cut, which I can bend to link with another hula hoop and then close it again. It's just not absolutely rigid but it can bend enough to make the Borromean rings configuration for example, which would otherwise be impossible if it was perfectly rigid.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "cannot twist"? I have a hard time interpreting this, sorry.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for some combination of Milnor invariants and stick number, though I've no idea how to make your physical restriction precise.

Comment: By the way you can't obtain the Borromean link with circles, so hula hoops are not allowed!